# cant see the video in chrome and also cant resize it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert a video in my webpage but in chrome its not showing i tried to run in elde its working there but i cant resize it.

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <video class="img/car.mp4" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

I made a parent div for the video container and place the video in there. I hope its correct. but cant resize the video as i want.

```
/* car video footer */
.parentDiv{
  height: 30vh;
  weight:100%;
  background-color: rgb(148, 15, 96);
}
video{
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: i did not know its my 5th day of learning thanks for answering

Comment: One advice for you, before posting here, make sure you have done all the research you could do for your problem and when you are not able to find a solution, post here with the code that doesn't work. Generally people are helpful here if some effort is shown, like in this case it is clear you needed to just search for the correct syntax. Many times you will find your questions closed / downvoted just because the solution could be found with some effort from your side

Comment: ok thanks for advice